# What is the real significance of new modifier in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

From the code below I wanted to know 
What is the difference between MyMethod2() and MyMethod3(). 
Why has .net provided  does not give compile error for not mentioning the new keyword    or in other words why has .net provided new keyword, if both implemnetation are same.

```
public class MyBase
{
    public virtual void MyMethod2()
    {
         //do something
    }
    public virtual void MyMethod3()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class MyDerived :MyBase
{
    public void MyMethod2()
    {
        base.MyMethod2();
    }
    public new void MyMethod3()
    {
        base.MyMethod3();
    } 
}


   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MyBase myClass = new MyDerived();
        myClass.MyMethod2(); //calls base class
        myClass.MyMethod3(); //calls base class
    }
```

Comment: Try it with a non-virtual method -- that is where the trickiness starts.

Comment: The _only_ effect of `new` here is to suppress the hides warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't give you a compile **error**, but it will give you a warning, and act as though you'd used the new keyword.